# SonarQube Scanner for Maven and SonarTsPlugin Cannot Run node

Tags: maven, typescript, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using SonarQube 5.6.1 for code analysis (code written in Spring Boot and Angular (using TypeScript)). [SonarQube Scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) 3.4.0.905 and [SonarTsPlugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) 1.1.0 are used for code scanning in Java and TypeScript, respectively.

In my `pom.xml`, I have the following properties set:

```
<frontend.directory>frontend</frontend.directory>
<sonar.host.url>http://sonarqube.some-url.local/</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.sources>src/main/java,${frontend.directory}/src/app,pom.xml</sonar.sources>
<sonar.exclusions>${frontend.directory}/node_modules/**</sonar.exclusions>
<sonar.tests>${frontend.directory}/src/app,src/test/java</sonar.tests>
<sonar.test.inclusions>**/*.spec.ts,src/test/java/**/*.java</sonar.test.inclusions>
<sonar.testExecutionReportPaths>${frontend.directory}/reports/ut_report.xml</sonar.testExecutionReportPaths>
<sonar.ts.coverage.lcovReportPath>${frontend.directory}/coverage/lcov.info</sonar.ts.coverage.lcovReportPath>
<sonar.ts.tslint.configPath>${frontend.directory}/tslint.json</sonar.ts.tslint.configPath>
<sonar.ts.tslint.nodePath>${frontend.directory}/node/node</sonar.ts.tslint.nodepath>
<sonar.ts.tslint.path>${frontend.directory}/node_modules/.bin/tslint</sonar.ts.tslint.path>
```

Please note that I am pointing `sonar.ts.tslint.nodePath` to the local node installed as following.

I use `frontend-maven-plugin` 1.6 to install `npm` and `node`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>

    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${frontend.directory}</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>install node and npm</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>v10.1.0</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>6.0.1</npmVersion>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
        ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I run `./mvnw sonar:sonar` to start the SonarQube scanner. However, when the SonarTsPlugin runs and goes to run `tslint`, the `nodePath` is ignored and the global node is used. This causes problems in my Jenkins box where I get the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project nsgra-web: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]`

This is odd to me since node is installed via `frontend-maven-plugin` and I am pointing to that `node` binary in `sonar.ts.tslint.nodePath`.

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Is the maven-frontend-plugin executed during the build? Default phase for maven-frontend-plugin is `generate-resources`, if this is not invoked, the plugin is in fact not executed. Try running `./mvnw package sonar:sonar`

Comment: Also make sure the version of SonarTsPlugin you're running is compatible with SonarQube 5.6.x. Later versions require 6.7.x +.

Comment: @user944849 can you expand on that? The [GitHub](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) has version 5.6+ in the [requirements section](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin#requirements). I fail to find any notion fo 6.7.x being required.

Comment: @AryanJ-NYC, the [plugin compatibility matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) shows that SonarTS version 1.1 is for SonarQube 5.6 - 6.6, while at least 1.5+ require 6.7+. This is for the SonarQube provided plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @user944849. Is SonarTs === SonarTsPlugin? That question may come off badly via text but it is genuine.

Comment: @AryanJ-NYC, I am not sure. I think the SonarTsPlugin was developed first, then SonarQube created their own (SonarTs). In your shoes, I'd make sure only one is installed, and that the version installed is appropriate for the version of SonarQube you're running. And make sure you're reading the right docs. Sometimes when I googled for SonarTs, documentation for SonarTsPlugin would come up. Potentially very confusing!

Comment: I agree! Thanks @user944849. I can confirm that I am using `SonarTsPlugin` and I am only consulting their docs.

Comment: We have the exact same setup and the error was fixed after using the following property: `<sonar.typescript.node>${frontend.directory}/node/node</sonar.typescript.node>` (see also: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarTS )

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [Aerus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538047/aerus) for your response.

I found the same issue inside docker pod using jenkins.

I had maven installed but not node, then maven create a local installation of node at ./node/ folder. When the TS sonar was trying to execute node to know the current version, the commented error arise and all .ts files was ignored.

I solved using your suggestion and adding this to the command line execution

```
-Dsonar.typescript.node=./node/node
```

Comment: On newer Sonar versions it's ``sonar.nodejs.executable``.